# How to stop Youtube Video (not HTML5) from javascript in iPad

Tags: javascript, jquery, youtube

I've created one app in HTML5 and javascript for iPad. 
I've put links in page, by clicking that will show/hide different youtube videos.

[Here is code](http://jsfiddle.net/parag1111/6Fv9r/1/)

- In ipad if i hide one youtube video and show another at that time previous video keeps playing in background till new video loads.
- I want to stop previous video playing before another video gets loaded.

*(I am using latest iOs, that plays youtube video in quicktime player.)*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/3bmxr/)

```
var vids = {
    vid1:"http://www.youtube.com/embed/87O_YA4rLyk",
    vid2:"http://www.youtube.com/embed/nQ2TsPhsWTA"
}    
$(function(e) {
  $(".video-section ul li").click(function(e) {
    $(this).hide();
    $(this).siblings().show();
    $("#vid").attr("src",vids[this.id]);
  });  
  $("#vid1").click();
});

<div class="videoContain-big">
  <p>
    <iframe id="vid" width="560" height="315" src="about:blank" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
  </p>
</div>
<div class="video-section">
  <ul>
    <li id="vid1">Click here to Change Video 1</li>
    <li id="vid2">Click here to Change Video 2</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

QuickTime exposes a number of methods to JavaScript. Some take the form of commands that operate on movies, such as `Play()`,`Stop()`,`Rewind()`, and so on. The rest operate on properties of QuickTime as a whole, the QuickTime plug-in, movies, or tracks. Most of these properties can be read or written using complementary Get and Set methods. Other properties, such as the QuickTime version, are read-only.

You can find a lot of information [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/QuickTime/Conceptual/QTScripting_JavaScript/bQTScripting_JavaScri_Document/QuickTimeandJavaScri.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001526-CH001-SW7)

Comment: Ok, but i can't get how to add it in my code. Cause I am loading Youtube Embed code only. I can not get ID of quicktime player.